# Spring boot microservices understanding concept question

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I've read some articles online and saw one tutorial regarding microservices. I'm confused with one thing that the tutorial said. Lets say we have simple architecture with eureka as disovery server and feign client. The tutorial said that this architecture uses server side load balancing and uses client side load balancing at the same time. First it get's services addresses and saves them in cache and then using that does client side load balancing. But I think its wrong. For me using feign client uses only client side load balancing. Server side is off the chart. There is no saving in cache, but the feign client is using eureka rather than cache memory. I could use server side load balancing with zuul, but then I wouldn't be using client load balancing am I right?

Second question is. Spring boot api gateway is also has built in load balancer and it also is using client side load balancing right?

I think the tutorial made some assumptions that weren't correct and now I'm left confused.